# Is there a more concise way of writing nested pattern matches in OCaml?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I find myself writing things like

```ml
match f x with
| Some x' -> f' x'
| None ->
  match g x with
  | Some x' -> g' x'
  | None ->
    match h x with
    | Some x' -> h' x'
    | None ->
      ...
```

Is there a cleaner way to write this kind of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you can write a function that tries a list of alternatives:

```ml
let rec try_with alts x = match alts with
  | [] -> None
  | (pred, follow) :: rest ->
     match pred x with
     | Some x -> follow x
     | None -> try_with rest x
...
try_with [f,f';g,g';h,h']
```

Alternatively, you can pattern match on tuples to test multiple patterns:

```
match f x, g x, h x with
| Some x, _, _ -> f' x
| _, Some x, _ -> g' x
| _, _, Some x -> h' x
```

And deep pattern matching is also possible (but doesn't really match your example):

```ml
let f = function
| [ _; Either.Left [|x|]; Either.Right [_;_,_,y] ] -> x + y
| _ -> 0
```

Comment: Beware that if `g` or `h` have side-effects, pattern matching on the tuple may not replicate the OP's code's behavior.